# How to dynamically change the background color of html tag in Spotfire Text Area

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, spotfire

## Spotfire7.11

I made a html table. I want to change the background color of table cell dynamically using input field or calculated value.

I want to set `bgcolor={dynamic value}`

[image]

Here is my .dxp file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TeM-L77K5gfR14kIfKHNDrGVLJ6AkCJX/view?usp=sharing

or

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hb5M_F_bujgFWr-gD1NXT3WL2gyCWYyX/view?usp=sharing

Any Idea?

I really appreciate your support.
Thanks!

Natasha.

Example:`＜TD style="HEIGHT: 21px; WIDTH: 248px; PADDING-LEFT: 20px;" bgcolor="#E6E6FA">First Name＜/TD＞`

Comment: Could not open your .dxp file. Please add a screenshot of your html table.

Comment: I uploaded my html table.
Let's say I want to change the background of "Email" cell to another color dynamically.

the dxp file is created with spotfire 7.11
check this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hb5M_F_bujgFWr-gD1NXT3WL2gyCWYyX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When you say color should change dynamically, what logic do you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks!
Let' say I want to change the color according to any calculated value(ie. calculated value=2 then 'red' or calculated value=1 then 'blue') or I can change the color using a drop down list.
＜TD style="HEIGHT: 21px; WIDTH: 248px; PADDING-LEFT: 20px;" bgcolor={Drop Down List value or Calculated Value}>Email＜/TD＞